# C++ - Can't access object member field

Tags: c++

I have a class called Node (it is a tree node). It has the following fields:
`string strValue`, `Node* parent`, `vector<Node*> children`

Node constructor takes a string as an argument, extracts the first word from it, and if the rest of the string isn't empty it creates a child node which does the same.

The first node in a tree is initialised like so:

```
root = Node(NULL, myString);
```

Node constructor:

```
Node(Node* parent, string str) 
{
 this->parent = parent;

 strValue = extractWord(str);

 if (str.length() > 0) {
  children.insert(children.end(), new Node(this, str);
 }
}
```

The above is a simplified version, but it should give a good view on how this should work.

My problem is that I am not able to access the parent's value. All of the Node fields are set as public. When I run the code that uses this specific operation: `parent->strValue`, the program crashes with no error message or anything similar. For example:

```
if (parent  == nullptr)
 return "Parent: NULL";
else
 return "Parent: " + parent->strValue;
```

If I use something like this instead:

```
if (parent  == nullptr)
 return "Parent: NULL";
else
 return "Parent: NOT NULL";
```

I executes without any problems.

I need to solve this issue, but I am out of ideas what could cause the problem.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: That sounds as if you have corrupted memory or already `delete`d the node. As mentioned above, we will need a [MCVE].

Comment: The root member, how is its strvalue initialised?

Comment: Check whether the field 'strValue' within the parent node is null. Might help.